# How to programatically adjust x and y axis of image in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cgrect

I am trying to centre my round image in the middle of my screen. (I have a video playing underneath it). I cannot seem to get this to centre based on the screen size. I am sure it is a simple solution , but if anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful

Here is the image of my simulator:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
    imageViewObject = UIImageView (frame: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), 150, 150, 150))
    imageViewObject.image = UIImage(named:"one.png")
    self.view.addSubview(imageViewObject)
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the position origin is the top left corner. You should use something like this instead:

```
imageViewObject = UIImageView (frame: CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame) - 150/2, 150, 150, 150))
```

Comment: That solved it! Could you please explain where the 150 came from? Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @DylanBuckley That is the width of your image view. You need to push back the view half of its width because you want one half of the image to be in the left half of the view and the other half of the image view in the right half. I can attach a drawing if that helps you.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I worked it out about two seconds after I posted it. Thank you for your help! I thought I was going mad!